# Scrapy (Python): Overwriting pre-existing data with same item name

Tags: python, scrapy

I was wondering if there is a way to *replace* old data with new data where the items are the same with Scrapy.

For example, say I had scraped stock data from yahoo finance for a particular stock. Then, later on after new data has been released, I want to update that stocks data in the same `output.csv` file I had used before.

I'm somewhat surprised that this isn't something Scrapy does already with it's command line (or they do I am just blind and can't find it).

I was thinking of maybe configuring `pipelines.py` to do the trick:

```
# pipelines.py:

class stockPipeline(object):
    def update_item(self, item, spider):
        with open('output.csv', 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for stock in reader:
                if stock['name'] == item['name']:
                    # Somehow get scrapy to overwrite this particular row...
                    # Or, maybe get DictWriter to do it for us instead of scrapy??
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the data pipelined into a real database and your problem would be solved right away.

For instance, let's say you'll switch to `MySQL` - in this case the problem would simply come down to making an insert if a record does not exist and making and update otherwise.